# celery redis:airflow celery with redis broker :Error connecting to redis Int or String expected

Tags: airflow

I'm using celery executor on airflow,set redis as celery as backend.I tried to run tutorial DAG in web click 'run'

airflow web click run for task 'print date'

[image: airflow web click run for task 'print date']

it throw an exception like this
[image]

the airflow scheduler log seems right with heartbeat,and on celery flower 2
workers is online.In airflow.cfg broker_url and celery_result_backend are the same,I cant not find any document in airflow to tells me config celery with redis.the redis host and port is right in log,[Int or String expected] what does is really mean?or can someone tell me how to debug this problem?

Comment: I reinstall older version of celery and redis,it works.thanks.